# Removing Outlook AddIn Sidebar Header

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I am working on a sidebar AddIn for Microsoft Outlook using Visual Studio Tools for Office.  However, I can't figure out how to get rid of the header outlook puts on my sidebar when I show it in Outlook.  Here is a screenshot showing the header, which contains the text "Sidebar Program": [Sidebar Screenshot](http://img205.imageshack.us/my.php?image=stackoverflowquestionai8.jpg).

I would prefer that header not show, along with the border around my sidebar.

I am adding the control to Outlook using (control is an instance of UserControl, either a hosted WPF control or a windows forms control)

`CustomTaskPane pane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(control, "Sidebar Program");`

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: I did solve it, but not using the Office 2007 stuff.  I had to hack the outlook window and shove my window in per this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/additional_panel_Outlook.aspx

Note, that article has a very shotty implementation that needs a lot of work, but it wasn't too difficult to get resizing and a fix for the initial box in the left corner bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do this using the Office 2007 CustomTaskPanes.  You have to shove your window into outlook like this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/additional_panel_Outlook.aspx